# update dynamically generated table row using jquery, when click on edit link

Tags: jquery, jsp

How to update a dynamically generated table row using jquery? I am able fetch a row, but failing to update it.
Should I call add function or I have to write a new function for it?

```
//Edit function
        $('#list').on('click', 'td:last-child', function (e) {
            var $tr = $(this).parent(),
                $tds = $tr.children(),
                sname = $tds.eq(0).text().trim(),
                mon = $tds.eq(1).text().trim();
                year = $tds.eq(2).text().trim();
            $('#G1 option').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().trim() == sname) {
                    $(this).prop('selected', true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $('#H1 option').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().trim() == mon) {
                    $(this).prop('selected', true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $('#I1 option').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().trim() == year) {
                    $(this).prop('selected', true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $('#J1').val($tds.eq(3).text().trim())
            $('#E1').val($tds.eq(4).text().trim())
            e.preventDefault();
                $('#irow').click();    //for update
        });
```

Is this the right way..? Can someone suggest me how to update a specific row....
And this is my demo code how it is working, http://jsfiddle.net/ca078/runsn84r/2/ 
Please help me in updating specific row of a table....

Comment: your question is not clear. can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Apul Gupta - I have a form, when i click on add, a row is added to the table "list"(here). And when i click on edit, specific row details are retrieved on the form, and again when i click on add this retrieved row should be updated.... (Add and edit part is working, but not update. demo code is shown in the above.). Instead of updating a row it is adding a new row to the table..

Answer (score 0):

declare the $tds as public and when you click on the edit button hide the add button and show an update button use the following code  for update button event

```
$("#btnUpdate").on("click"),function(){

      $tds.eq(0).text(value1);
      $tds.eq(1).text(value2);
      $tds.eq(2).text(value3);
});
```

if you declare a variable inside a function then its scope is only inside that function and it is a private variable in this case declare $tds before declaring the add and update methods like this

```
var $tds=null;

        $('#list').on('click', 'td:last-child', function (e) {
var $tr = $(this).parent(),
                $tds = $tr.children(),
..................
.........

});

$("#btnUpdate").on("click"),function(){
 $tds.eq(0).text(value1);
....................
..............
});
```

each time you clicked the edit button the $tds value updated with new value because its declared outside the function you can use that $tds for update method too

Comment: Thank you for replying @Optimus. Can u tell me, how it should be declared as public? I am new to jquery, I just know basics. var tds=$tr.children(); - Is this correct way..?

Comment: How do i show update button? When i am doing this, Edit button is hided in table, but not displaying with update button. $('a').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show('#Update');
});

Comment: you don't have to hide the edit button hide the add button  and then show the update button then after updating hide update and show add

Comment: -where should i call this, after $('#list').on('click', 'td:last-child', function (e) {.....}); or as u shown above..? I tried as u shown above, but it is not working, what is the mistake I have done? $("#Update").show(function(e){
              if($('#G1').val()){$tds = $tr.children(),
                    sname = $tds.eq(0).text().trim(),
                    mon = $tds.eq(1).text().trim();
                    year = $tds.eq(2).text().trim();........ });

Comment: It is adding new row instead. And This is the updated fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/ca078/runsn84r/4/

Comment: you dont have to find the td using  $('#list tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)').html($('#G1').val()); because the current td object is already saved in  $tds just use that updating the table like this $tds.eq(0).text(value1);